# How to update the table on the page, after submitting the form via AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form and a table. When I submit a form using AJAX, I need to see the result immediately in the table, without rebooting p.

That is the order of such.
1. Fill out the form
2. I send through AJAX in a DB
3. I reload the page, and I see the result

---

```
//AJAX -
        $("#reg").submit(function(event){
          var fn = document.getElementById('fn').value,
              ln = document.getElementById('ln').value,
              phone =  document.getElementById('phone').value;
              event.preventDefault();

         //вторая проверка на валидацию
            if (fn.length < 3 ||  ln.length < 3 || phone.length < 6) {
                console.log('некорректно фрорма регист')
            } else {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:  'regist.php',

                    data: {
                        First:fn, 
                        Last:ln, 
                        'Telephone[0]':phone
                    },

                    success: function( response ){ 
                        jQuery('#reg')[0].reset();//отчистить форму
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                }); 

            } 
        });
```

---

```
   <div class="table">
         <table border="1" >
            <thead>
               <tr>
              <th>ID R </th><th>ID U</th><th>Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone 1</th><th>Phone 2</th><th style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">X</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>


            <tbody id='trash'>
               //get table таблицу
               <?php require_once('table.php'); ?>
            </tbody>


         </table>

     //get info from table.   
         <form method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="get_info" value="Show list" class="show_list" />
         </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: within the "success" function of your ajax call (i.e. after it completes) you must use Javascript to modify the table.  Did you try anything? It would probably make sense if the ajax call returns some relevant data in its response to enable you to update the table as needed.

Comment: i partially understood what you said, if I make a separate request for the table, and in success call it something, it will work? and is it possible to do so?

Comment: why a separate request? You already have an ajax request (going to regist.php), maybe you can return some data from there to tell you how to change the table. I don't know your server-side, so maybe that's impossible, but that would be my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I created another request and call it in register.

---

```
//AJAX - добавить юзера
    $("#reg").submit(function(event){
      var fn = document.getElementById('fn').value,
          ln = document.getElementById('ln').value,
          phone =  document.getElementById('phone').value;

        event.preventDefault();

      //вторая проверка на валидацию
      if (fn.length < 3 ||  ln.length < 3 || phone.length < 6) {
        console.log('Некорректно Заполнена фрорма регистрации')
      } else {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url:  'regist.php',
          data: {
            First:fn, 
            Last:ln, 
           'Telephone[0]':phone
          },
          success: function( response ){ 
            jQuery('#reg')[0].reset();//отчистить форму
            dynamicTable();//строка 254 | динамически обновить табл.
            console.log(response);
          }
        }); 
      } 
    });
```

---

```
//AJAX -динамически обновить табл.    
  function dynamicTable() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url:  'table.php',
      dataType: "html", 
      success: function( html ){
        // console.log(html);
        $("#trash").html(html);
      }
    }); 
  }
```